# How to make a CSS overlay on top of images from database

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have a thumbnails that have a transparent overlay, so when a user hovers over the image, it will have in the center an 'x' glyphicon and text under it saying 'delete photo'. It would need to be pure css3 and is for a user to delete an image from their page, which is done through a db. However, how do I ensure that it will work for images that are called from a database to have the overlay instead of hard-coding the images into the html?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <img src="img1" data-src="" class="img-responsive">
         <img src="img2" data-src="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

thank you.

Comment: What's the difference between images that are hard coded, and images that are loaded from the database? An image is an image. What exactly you need help with? The task seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Basic search would show that this question has ben asked *thousands* of times before.

Comment: @Narxx, sorry, I am new to advanced methods, I guess...

Comment: LGSon, no worries. I had not seen your answer earlier. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you use a pseudo element like this

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
span:hover:after {
  content: 'X \A' attr(data-text);
  white-space: pre;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<span data-text="Delete image">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/animals/3" data-src="" class="img-responsive">
</span>
```

Comment: this seems pretty good, but can I have a div instead of using a span?

Comment: @Krystyna Of course you can, just change and it will work the same

Answer (score 0):

This is one option to acomplish what you want with pure css

```css
.img-wrap:hover > .img-options{
  display: block;
}

.img-options{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="img-wrap">
           <img src="img1" data-src="" class="img-responsive">
           <div class="img-options">
             delete image 
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This way you can hide/show the options for each image.
Make sure to complete the css code to make the img-options element to be absolute positioned above the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css 2.1 selector `:hover` on the container element and set the X icon as a transparent background image of that container.

```
.col-md-12:hover {
    background-image: url(x-icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center
}
```

Instead of .col-md-12 you should rather use a generic class name.

Comment: I guess I can have another div within the col-md-12, and give that the selector for individual images...